# D3 extra tag over axis with custom shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to replicate these tags with a triangle at the end in D3 to show the last data points.

The way I can think of is to append a triangle at the end of a rect element, but is quite messy since I have to align the triangle with the rectangle position. I was wonder if there was there a better way of doing it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `path` with a fill to get the solid shape you are looking for:

```
.join("path")
.attr("d", (d, i) => `M ${1} ${yScale(d)} l 6,-6 h 24 v 12 h -24 l -6,-6`)
.attr("fill", (d, i) => d3.schemeTableau10[i])
```

This is simpler than drawing a `rect` and then bolting on the little triangle. See below:

```js
const width = 200;
const height = 180;
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range([160, 10]);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
const yAxisG = svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(60, 10)`).call(yAxis);
const markerY = [0.25, 0.45, 0.65];
const markers = yAxisG.selectAll(".marker")
  .data(markerY)
  .join("path")
  .attr("d", (d, i) => `M ${1} ${yScale(d)} l 6,-6 h 24 v 12 h -24 l -6,-6`)
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => d3.schemeTableau10[i])

const labels = yAxisG.selectAll(".label")
  .data(markerY)
  .join("text")
  .text(d => d)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d))
  .attr("dx", 8)
  .attr("dy", 4)
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("fill", "#000");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Robin! This works. Do you know where I can get documentation for the short hand notations you used? I.e. ```l, h, v```? I can only find this http://using-d3js.com/05_01_paths.html, which seems to do a little different from how you used it

Comment: @ZooPanda - this doco is useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths. Use of lowercase 'h' 'l' and 'v' mean they are relative to the last point. User of uppercase 'H' 'L' and 'V' mean they use absolute coordinates.